# How to get a list of objects from a JSP in a Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have some issues with my code. I try to get a list of object from a jsp in my controller to send it to my service with a POST

When I try to get the list in my controller with the annotation @ModelAttribute it return me an empty list. Here my controller class and my jsp

Controller

```
    @GetMapping("/OvedraftsCustomer")
    public String getOverdraftsCustomers(ModelMap model){
        List<AccountDTO> overdraftAccounts = overdraftService.getOverdraftAccounts();
        model.addAttribute("overdraftAccounts",overdraftAccounts);
        return "agios/displayOverdraftCustomers";
    }


    @PostMapping("/agioDetails")
    public String getOverDraftDetails(@ModelAttribute("account") ArrayList<AccountDTO> account, BindingResult binding, ModelMap model) throws ParseException {
        model.addAttribute("accounts",account);
        logger.info("taille : " + account.size());
        return "redirect:agiosInfo";
    }
```

JSP

```
<table class="w3-table-all w3-hoverable">

        <tr class="w3-hover-blue w3-blue">
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Prénom </th>
            <th>iban</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>Découvert Autorisé</th>
            <th>Découvert actuel</th>
            <th>Taux débiteurs</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${overdraftAccounts}" var="overdraftAccounts">
            <tr class="w3-hover-blue">
                <td><c:out value="${overdraftAccounts.getCustomer().getName()}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${overdraftAccounts.getCustomer().getSurname()}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${overdraftAccounts.getIban()}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${overdraftAccounts.getCustomer().getEmail()}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${overdraftAccounts.getCustomer().getAgioParameters().getAuthorizedOverdraft()}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${overdraftAccounts.getOldBalances().get(overdraftAccounts.getOldBalances().size()-1).getBalance()}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${overdraftAccounts.getCustomer().getAgioParameters().getBorrowingRate()}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
        </br>
        </br>

    <form method="POST" action="/agioDetails" modelAttribute="account">
       <c:forEach var="test" items="${accounts}" varStatus="status">
            <form:input path="accounts[${status.index}].getIban()" name="iban" id="iban" value="test.getIban()" />
            <form:input path="accounts[${status.index}].getBalance()" name="balance" id="balance" value="test.getBalance()" />
            <form:input path="accounts[${status.index}].oldBalances()" name="oldBalances" id="oldBalances" value="test.getOldBalances()" />
            <form:input path="accounts[${status.index}].getCustomer()" name="customer" id="customer" value="test.getCustomer()" />
            <form:input path="accounts[${status.index}].getAgios()" name="agios" id="agios" value="test.getAgios()" />
        </c:forEach>
        </br>
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input class="w3-button w3-padding-large w3-blue" type="submit" value="Consulter le détail"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Currently, I am just trying to get the list in my controller from my jsp therefore I just try to see if my list is not empty in my controller. If anyone can help me with this issue and explain what i have done wrongly please..

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think your way of making a post request to your controller is little bit messy, so I'll recommend that you try to do this:

First in your java Create a Entity class for your Details,
e.g.

Details.java

```
public class Details {
    private String iban;
    private Integer balance;
    private Integer oldBalances;
    private String customer;
    private String agios;
    public String getIban() {
        return iban;
    }
    public void setIban(String iban) {
        this.iban = iban;
    }
    public Integer getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
    public void setBalance(Integer balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public Integer getOldBalances() {
        return oldBalances;
    }
    public void setOldBalances(Integer oldBalances) {
        this.oldBalances = oldBalances;
    }
    public String getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }
    public void setCustomer(String customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
    public String getAgios() {
        return agios;
    }
    public void setAgios(String agios) {
        this.agios = agios;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Details [iban=" + iban + ", balance=" + balance + ", oldBalances=" + oldBalances + ", customer="
                + customer + ", agios=" + agios + "]";
    }

}
```

and add this id to your button"btnSubmit" and put this to your javascipt(I'm using jquery)

```
var details = {};
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
details.iban = $("#iban").val();
details.balance = $("#balance ").val();
details.oldBalances = $("#oldBalances").val();
details.customer = $("#customer ").val();
details.agios = $("#agios ").val();
$.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type":"application/json"  
          },
          url: "/agioDetails",
          data: JSON.stringify(details ),
          success: function( result ) {
           alert("okay");
          }
          });
})
```

and do this to your controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/agioDetails", consumes = "application/json")
    ModelAndView getRecord(@RequestBody Details details) throws SQLException, Exception {
        System.out.println(details);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        return mv;
    }
```

the datas should have been passed to your java cotroller without errors.

Comment: Hello, first thank you for you answer, i wanted to do it in spring because I am not familiar at all with jquery and ajax but nervermind. I have implemented your solution but it seems to return me just an object and not a list of object and all the attributes are null

Comment: you can return an object or list an object using your controller, 
you just do it this way,


`model.addAtrribute("any_name_youwant","any_object_you_want");
model.addAtrribute("another_name_youwant","another_object_you_want");
 ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("fileName_of_your_jsp");
        return mv; `


and you can acces it in your html using 

${any_name_youwant}